# Exception "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse

I have found a old project called "cogito" relesed more than 10 years ago. Now technical issues:

- cogito is composed by just two folders zipped (app and WEB-inf)
- only file .class were present (no source) and I decompiled (.class files) them with a software
  called  "jd"
- In the directory with .class I added the source files .java
- I have imported directories app and WEB-inf directory in eclipse workspace
- I run evrythings getting this message error:Exception in thread "main"
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "files" is null
  at org.fontbox.afm.AFMParser.main(AFMParser.java:318)
- in the first line of the code there is this message error:Multiple markers at this line

  - The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
    referenced from
    required .class files
  - The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
    referenced from required .class files
  - Syntax error on tokens, delete these token

Any guess?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If my answer helped you solve the problem, please accept it by clicking the gray checkmark next to it. It will earn you two reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have declared a reference type and have not assigned it yet, like this:

```
Integer myInteger;
```

Now, if you try to use `myInteger`, because it is not pointing to anything yet, it will throw an `NullPointerException`. Hence the name. The way to fix it is to *assign* it a pointer first:

```
Integer myInteger;
myInteger = new Integer(20);
```

before using it. Perhaps, because the code is 10 years old, and outdated, when trying to compile it in new Java version it fails.